# Custom ACL Authorization and return rows based on the permission

Tags: c#, webforms, authorization, acl, abac

I'm building some sort of a complicated inventory system, accepting offers from suppliers, etc.

Normally I would have basic permissions like Read/Write/Edit/Delete and I can easily update read and write bool variables on each page to check if true do this, else do that.

But that's not the case. I have some permissions like (Owner, SamePseudoCity) which respectively means that the user is allowed access to the records he only created, and the other means returning the records that belongs to the PsuedoCity as the user.

Currently the UI has local variables with the applicable permissions and when the UI request some data from the db it calls the BL that first get the permissions the user is entitled to and bind them to UI/Page local variables.

Also it checks if the permission list contains 'Owner' then it will get the records created by the UserID, if it contains 'SamePseudoCity' it will get all the records in the same city.

I'm not sure if this is a good design and if I can modify it. I know there is no right or wrong here but there's smelly-design, okay-design, and better-design. So I'm just looking for some ideas if someone implemented this before.

It took a lot to explain my problem if it's still not clear please let me know and I can post some snippets from my code.

Comment: use a database that does row security or use a well-tested .net authn/autho library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getting to grips with your requirements

What you need is an authorization framework that is capable enough of handling your requirements. In your post, you mention that you have

- Permissions e.g. Read/Write/Edit/Delete
- other parameters e.g. Owner, SamePseudoCity that mean different things:

  - user is allowed access to the records he only created
  - returning the records that belongs to the PsuedoCity as the user.

### Attribute-based access control

You need to turn to [tag: ABAC] (attribute based access control) which will give you the ability to define your requirements using attributes (key-value pairs) and policies. The policies are maintained and evaluated inside a 3rd party engine called the Policy Decision Point (PDP).

ABAC is a standard defined by [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/). It is an evolution of RBAC (role-based access control). XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language is an implementation of ABAC,

You can apply [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) to different layers in your architecture from the UI (presentation tier) to the business tier and all the way down to your data tier.

Policies are expressed in [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa) or [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml).

### Example:

```
namespace stackoverflow{
```

You first define your attributes

```
    namespace user{
        attribute identifier{
            category = subjectCat
            id = "user.identifier"
            type = string
        }   
        attribute city{
            category = subjectCat
            id = "user.city"
            type = string
        }           
    }
    namespace item{
        attribute owner{
            category = resourceCat
            id = "item.owner"
            type = string
        }
        attribute city{
            category = resourceCat
            id = "item.city"
            type = string
        }
    }
    attribute actionId{
        category = actionCat
        id = "actionId"
        type = string
    }
```

Then you define the policies that use these attributes

```
    /**
     * Control access to the inventory
     */
    policy inventory{
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Anyone can view a record they own
         */
        rule viewRecord{
            target clause actionId == "view"
            condition user.identifier == item.owner
            permit
        }
        /**
         * Anyone can view a record that is in the same city
         */
        rule viewRecordsSameCity{
            target clause actionId == "view"
            condition user.city == item.city
            permit          
        }
    }
}
```

#### Next step

You then need to deploy a Policy Decision Point / Policy Server. You can choose from several:

- Axiomatics Policy Server (disclaimer I work for Axiomatics)
- SunXACML
- Oracle Entitlements Server
- WSO2 Identity Server

If you want to apply your policies to both the UI and the database, then you can use a feature called *dynamic data masking* via an Axiomatics product called [Data Access Filter MD](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-databases.html).

[image: ADAF MD Architecture]

### Update

The OP later commented the following

> ABAC" never heard of it and it sounds brilliant but I assume I need access to a dedicated server or a VPS to install the PDP, right ? .. I know this can be too much to ask but I have 3 questions, Can I programmatically change the rules ? Is it possible to implement this scenario where Every product has a pseudo city and every manager also has a pseudo city and managers are only allowed access to their own city products ? is it possible do simple read/write/edit rules and hide and show UI based on that ? –

So first off, let's start with the ABAC architectural diagram:

- The PEP is the policy enforcement point, the piece responsible for protecting your apps, APIs, and databases. It enforces authorization decisions.
- The PDP is the policy decision point, the piece responsible for evaluating policies and reaching decisions. It processes requests it receives from the PEP and returns authorization decisions (Permit, Deny).
- The PAP is the policy administration point where you define and manage your policies
- the PIP is the policy information point. It's the interface the PDP uses to connect to third party attribute sources e.g. A user LDAP, a database, or a web service. The PDP uses the PIP when it needs to know more about the user or the resource.

[image: ABAC XACML Architecture]

> I assume I need access to a dedicated server or a VPS to install the PDP, right ?

Yes, you would install the PDP on a server (or the cloud). It becomes part of your infrastructure.

> Can I programmatically change the rules?

Yes you can. The Axiomatics PAP has an API that you can use to upload, export, and create policies programmatically.

> Is it possible to implement this scenario where Every product has a pseudo city and every manager also has a pseudo city and managers are only allowed access to their own city products ?

Yes, that is actually what I wrote in my original example and that is the beauty of ABAC. You write a single policy that works no matter the number of cities: `A user can view a record if user.city==record.city`

> is it possible do simple read/write/edit rules and hide and show UI based on that ?

Yes, you can use any number of attributes in your policies. So for instance you could have:

- Deny users access to records outside their city
- users can view records
- a user can edit a record they own
- a user can approve a record they do not own

You can use the logic to drive authorization in your UI or your business layer or even at the data layer. So you could ask the PDP:

- Can I show the Edit button?
- Can I show the Details button?
- Can I show the Delete button?

Comment: "ABAC" never heard of it and it sounds brilliant but I assume I need access to a dedicated server or a VPS to install the PDP, right ? .. I know this can be too much to ask but I have 3 questions, Can I programaticaly change the rules ? Is it possible to implement this scenario where Every product has a pseudo city and every manager also has a pseudo city and managers are only allowed access to their own city products ? is it possible do simple read/write/edit rules and hide and show UI based on that ?